# Убрать дубликаты в списке байт массивов

Tags: c#

Есть список List байт массивов, как удалить из него все одинаковые элементы оставив только их первые вхождения?

Вот пример, но он не работает:

```
byte[] t1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("111");
byte[] t2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("222");
var oldlist = new List<byte[]>() {t1, t2, t1};

var newlist = new List<byte[]>();

foreach (var item in oldlist)
{
    var arr_as_list = item.ToList();
    var arr = arr_as_list.Distinct().ToArray();
    newlist.Add(arr);
}
```

Подскажите может где тут ошибка?

Comment: newList = oldList.Distinct().ToList(); не то, что вам надо?

Comment: @Vlad, опередил )

Comment: А что мне надо?

Comment: @Vlad, только если действительно так создается. Если это просто массивы с одинаковыми значениями - такой подход не будет работать

Comment: @polsok, удалить одинаковые элементы из списка? Хотя кто знает.

Comment: @Grundy, ну да. Потому я и уточнил. Если этого достаточно, то нет смысла городить сравнение по содержимому массивов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ

```
        byte[] t1 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("111");
        byte[] t2 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("222");
        var list = new List<byte[]>() { t1, t2, t1 };

        list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

не надо усложнять то что очень просто